# Silverlight Triggers in a Button Template?

Tags: silverlight, triggers

Does anyone have a functioning example of how to use triggers in a Silverlight Button Template using the Microsoft.Expression.Interactivity dlls?

I want to respond to the click event in a Button's template defined in a style, by triggering an animation.

Comment: A button template has predefined states (you don't have to set up the triggers). Are you using Blend? Version 3?

Comment: The Button's click event does not have a corresponding state.  There is no "Click" state.  So yeah, triggers are required.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

looks like it wasn't possible at that time.

Answer (score 2):

You want to use an `EventTrigger` that fires a `GoToStateAction`

```
<Button x:Name="button" Height="53" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="173,124,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="147" Content="Button">
    <i:Interaction.Triggers>
        <i:EventTrigger EventName="Click">
            <ic:GoToStateAction TargetName="checkBox" StateName="Checked"/>
        </i:EventTrigger>
    </i:Interaction.Triggers>
</Button>
<CheckBox x:Name="checkBox" Height="24" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="173,206,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="147" Content="CheckBox"/>
```

To do this in Blend you would drag a `GoToStateAction` onto the button and then set the TargetName property to the target UIElement and the StateName property to the desired state.

Comment: That's not in a template though - is it not possible to do it in a template?  I want all buttons to have the same animation once clicked.

Answer (score 0):

You can always use the VisualStateManager and change to the "Click" state by handling the click event of a Button.

```
void myButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs)
{
     VisualStateManager.GoToState(this, "Click", true);
}
```

You will also need to define a style and state in the XAML code.

```
<Style x:Key="ButtonStyle" TargetType="Button">       
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
                        <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                            <VisualStateGroup x:Name="StateGroup">
                               <VisualState x:Name="ActiveLink">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        //animations go here
                              ...
```

Also, remember that Button objects have a bunch of predefine states like Disabled, Pressed (Click?), MouseOver, and Normal.

Comment: Pressed is not the same as Click - they are two totally different things.

And templates don't have a corresponding code-behind.

Triggers were added to Silverlight via the Interactivity.dll, I just can't seem to find much documentation regarding how to use them